# Use variable in jQuery CSS attribute line

Tags: jquery, css, styles, height, attr

What I am attempting to do is calculate the browser height, reduce that number by about 20%, then assign that number to the height of an element. The problem is the element lies within a scrollable div, so just assigning `height: 80%` won't work as I want the browser height not the parent div height. Another issue is I must use the `!important` syntax to force it, unfortunately.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var browserHeight = jQuery(window).height();
var desiredHeight = browserHeight * 0.8;
jQuery('##myID .myClass').attr('style', 'height: 100px !important');
```

I just need to figure out how to replace `100px` with `desiredHeight`, without losing `!important`.

If you could assist me, I'd surely appreciate it! Even if you have a different (maybe better) method in mind. :)

Comment: jQuery('#myID .myClass').attr('style', 'height: '+desiredHeight+'px !important');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just concatenate the string with the variable:

```
$('#myID .myClass').attr('style', 'height: ' + Math.round(desiredHeight) + 'px !important');
```

Note: I removed the extra pound symbol from the selector, that would have cause an exception.  Also, you shouldn't need the important since this is an inline style, and will override all css rules for the element.  I would switch this to use the css method as such:

```
$('#myID .myClass').css('height', desiredHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered, you were the quickest. :) For some reason it's not assigning that to the CSS, yet there's no errors and it doesn't skip over the code. I have some investigating to do. PS. I absolutely do need the !important and the double # and jQuery instead of $ - it's a cfm file. ;)

Comment: Ahh cfm, i see. I still don't see why you would need the !important, the inline will override all css rules that apply to that element.  Not sure why this is not working for you.

Comment: I need it because the element I want to modify already has an in-line value which I cannot remove.

Comment: Oh I see - you have a height attribute on the element?  Try creating a jsfiddle

Comment: Hey thanks Justin! Your suggestion worked just fine, the issue was I was running the code before the element was fully loaded, so it didn't apply it. Thanks a ton! Also, wanted to say thanks for mentioning the math round - good thinking!

Answer (score 1):

```
var browserHeight = $(window).height();
var desiredHeight = browserHeight * 0.8;
jQuery('##myID .myClass').attr('style', 'height: '+ desiredHeight +'px !important');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var browserHeight = jQuery(window).height();
var desiredHeight = browserHeight * 0.8;
jQuery('##myID .myClass').attr('style', 'height: '+desiredHeight+'px !important');
```